# How to use a p-value sampling distribution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, application, sampling-distribution

As part of my research I have been looking into the sampling distribution of p-values. Even though p-values are on their way out, they are still used ubiquitously with the normal $\alpha$ =.05 cutoff (and in my opinion they will probably continue to be used for a while to come). There has only ever been (as far as I can tell) one paper published [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2533093?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) that has attempted to derive a closed form in the simplest case, and papers [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2686051?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) and [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3087299?seq=2#metadata_info_tab_contents) have looked into the expected value and median of such a distribution.

One thing I have noticed is even though the theoretical results are in of themselves fascinating, the practical results seem lacking. What more information could we possibly get from knowing the sampling distribution of the p-value that the sampling distribution of the mean couldn't provide us with (i.e. if I took a bootstrap of the p-value and, when $\sigma$ is known,$\frac{\bar{X}-\mu_{0}}{\sigma}$, which is the effect size, putting a confidence interval on this effect size would seem to give me more information than a distribution of p-values, since it tells me the size of an effect and if it could be in the ballpark of 0, which in this case is the point-null hypothesis).

I've thought about the possible applications to multiple testing and conducting multiple experiments, but I'm not sure of what else. What do ya'll think? Are there any benefits to knowing the sampling distribution of the p-value?

Comment: In the case where the data are discrete, as applies for the Fisher exact test eg, the induced discreteness of the sampling distribution of the p-value is the reason that the test is conservative. Thus it is also the reason for the various "corrections" that have been proposed.